# Issue with Ninject InSingletonScope... ViewModel is getting constructed multiple times

Tags: ninject

I'm using DataTemplates in a ViewModel first approach.

I need to share a singleton ViewModel with multiple views.

So, I setup a simple ViewModel for each view and, using Ninject, I'm getting from the Kernel a reference to the singleton viewmodel...so I thought.

Structure:

MainViewModel

- ObservableCollection TabViewModels {get; set;}
- TabViewModels.Add(new View1ViewModel());

View1ViewModel

- in constructor...getting reference to MainViewModel (singleton)

This causes a circular reference...the constructor in MainViewModel is executing each time around the circle.

I'm binding the viewmodel in Ninject this way...

```
Bind<GridViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

I'm getting the reference this way...

```
private MainViewModel _mvm;

public View1ViewModel()
{
    _mvm = ViewModelLocator.MainViewModel; 
    //or
    _mvm = ViewModelLocator.Kernel.Get<MainViewModel();
    //both produce the same results
}
```

Comment: Please post some more code of the Main View Model and the View1ViewMOdel, it's not particulary easy to understand what you are trying to tell.
You could try the following feature of Ninject to break the circulare reference / prevent the stack overflow (i guess there is one): Do not construct the View1ViewModel in the ctor of the MainViewModel but rather implement a separate MainViewModel.Initialize() method which does so. Then add OnActivation(x => x.Initialize()) to the binding of the MainViewModel.

Comment: I'm expanding my understanding of ViewModel first design by trying out Caliburn.Micro. It seems they have good example of how to successfully incorporate DependencyInjection with a ViewModel first approach. That is the path I'm pursuing at this moment.